# Determine MySql mode from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, strict-mode

Is there any way to find if mysql server is in strict mode or not from PHP?
I need to find out this at runtime(in installation script), so I can inform user if his system satisfy script requirements.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether it's completely the same but you might want to have a look at [$MySQLi_Driver->$report_mode](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php#mysqli-driver.props.report-mode).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT @@sql_mode;` will give what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can run a simple query like

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

This should be able to get you your SQL mode. There is more information at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html about how you can manage the mode if need be.